# C# Efficiently store large int data

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, storage

Evening all, I'm in a predicament where I can't decide/know of the best method for storing "simple" but large amounts of `int` datatypes.

Now at the moment I was using a flattened array `int[] TheData = new int[size * size];`, because I was only storing 1 layer but now I'm needing at least 3 layers. The initial through process was to either use a:

`Dictionary<uint, int[]> TheNewData = new Dictionary<uint, int[]>();` *(The key is the layer)*

But I've not had much experience with dictionaries so I believe this would cause problems with accessing the data via array index like in the flat array `TheData[x + y * width] = ...`

or simply:

`int[,] TheNewData = new int[LayerCount, size * size];`

*The above one makes me feel very dirty.*

I could even just triple the original flat array size and apply offset to the next layer...

Anyway I've also got to take into account ridiculously large maps, like say the width x hight was **1,000 x 1,000** *(tiles)* that's **1,000,000** tiles to be stored as `int`'s somewhere *(I think...)*. So data access needs to be fairly fast as I've also go to deal with updating potentially the entire "**active**" layer.

*If you could please "explain" why your suggested method is best suited that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.*

Comment: If you're going to have N objects identified by [0, 1, ... N-1], there's no reason to use a dictionary over an array.

Comment: is data sparse? What access pattern is needed (random access or sequential)?

Comment: The data is accessed randomly in some cases, so in drawing to the canvas, the tileIndex (0,1, ... N-1) is stored relative to the canvas in the array (tile(1) place at 3x, 1y).

Comment: Why does a two dimensional array make you feel dirty? Except perhaps because it should be a three dimensional array?

Comment: I've never liked 2D arrays mostly because I'm usually programming in c++ which may say it all. So I haven't got much knowledge on c# and it's clear to me that there are a lot of very distinct differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're storing multiple NxN grids, what's wrong with `int[,,] foo = new int[LayerCount, size, size];`? It's easy to index and plenty fast if you're doing random access. If you're doing sequential access, you can get better performance with jagged arrays, but initializing them is a bit inconvenient.

The other problem with multidimensional arrays (i.e. `int[,,]`) is that they require a single contiguous block of memory. If you only have three layers of 1000 x 1000, that's not a problem. Because you're only talking 12 megabytes. But if your size was 1,000,000 rather than 1,000, you'd be allocating 12 *giga*bytes, which could give you some trouble.

A jagged array, by the way, is of the form `int[][][] foo = new int[LayerCount][][];` You then have to initialize the other dimensions individually. It's not difficult, just messy. But it does get around needing a single contiguous block of memory, but at the cost of some runtime performance if you're accessing it randomly.

Or, you could use a hybrid:  `int[,][]`, which you can think of as an array of two-dimensional arrays. In this case, each layer is a single allocation.

Whatever the case, if you know the size of your layers and you know how many you have, there's really no reason to use anything but an array.

You could of course make a single one-dimensional array line `int[] messy = new int[LayerCount * size * size]`, and do your own indexing. Seems like a lot of unnecessary work, though.

For some information about the performance characteristics of arrays in C#, see http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/08/are-jagged-arrays-faster-than-rectangular-arrays/. I haven't done any performance comparisons with three dimensional arrays, but I would expect them to be similar.

Comment: Thank you, this has certainly cleared up a lot of my confusion. Also great explanation, again thank you.